# Upload file and validate csrf token with express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, multer

I'm working with `mongodb`, `nodejs` and `express`. 
I'have a form that send a `post` request for upload a file with `multer-gridfs`.
Inside the form i have only the `input` for upload the file and an `hidden input` for the `csrf`. The request is sent via `ajax`. The problem is the validation of the `csrf token` when i send the ajax request

**FORM FOR UPLOAD THE IMAGE**

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id="upload-file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
function upload_image(){
    console.log('upload image')
    var fd = new FormData($("#upload-file-form").get(0));
    console.log(fd);
    var token = $('input[name="_csrf"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/posts/upload' ,
        data: {fd: fd, _csrf: token },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        }
    })
}
```

**ERROR**

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at csrf (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/csurf/index.js:112:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/pero/motoWebApp/node_modules/express-session/index.js:495:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

**ROUTE THAT LISTEN AJAX REQUEST**

```
const GridFsStorage             = require('multer-gridfs-storage'),
      multer                    = require('multer');

const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/app";

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploaded_images' //collection name
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
});


router.post('/posts/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){ 
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.file.filename))
});
```

I saw that for validate the `csrf` toke via `ajax` you have to specify it inside the `data` attribute of the ajax request and i did this. I think that the problem is caused by the attributes `processData` and `contentType`
that are set to `false`.

If i remove those attributes the code doesn't raise the `invalid csrf token` error but in the broswer it prints `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`

Comment: Are you using an appropriate session-middleware/cookie-parser?

Comment: yes, i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found that for upload an image and validate the `csrf` token instead of passing the `csrf` token inside the `data` attribute of the `ajax` call you should set it inside the `header` attribute of the `ajax` call

You have to do something like this

```
var form = $("#upload-file-form");
var fd = new FormData(form.get(0));
var token = $("#upload-file-form input[name='_csrf']").val();
$.ajax({
        url: '/posts/upload' ,
        headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": <your token>},
        data: {your datas},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
   });
```